# Symfony 3, doctrine Fatal error, Scalar type declaration 'integer' must be unqualified

Tags: doctrine, symfony, php-7

I have this code :

```
class Entity
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="Integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;
    ...
}
```

when I try to run doctrine:schema:update, I get

```
Fatal error, Scalar type declaration 'integer' must be unqualified
```

Why do I get this error? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that instead of Column(type="Integer"), I should have typed Column(type="integer"). It was just a matter of case.